# Adding Category and Subcategories in a multiselect dropdown in Channel Form

Tags: categories, channel-form

I am using channel form to allow users to add a new entry.
I need to output a category to allow then to select multiple categories and sub categories.
The following code works but it does not order the sub cats below the parent Category:

```
<select name="category[]" size="100" multiple="multiple" id="multiSelect">
{exp:query sql="SELECT cat_name, cat_id FROM exp_categories WHERE group_id='3'"}
<option value='{cat_id}'>{cat_name}</option>
{/exp:query}
</select>
```

I would like to see the categories listing as:

```
Parent 1
 child 1.1
 child 1.2
Parent 2
 Child 2.1
 Child 2.2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The docs provide a couple of syntax options](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_form/#categories):

```
{category_menu}
        <label for="categories">Categories</label>
        <select name="category[]" id="categories" size="4" multiple="multiple">
                {select_options}
        </select>
{/category_menu}
```

Or, for finer control:

```
<select name="category[]" id="categories" size="4" multiple="multiple">
        {categories}
                <option value="{category_id}"{selected}>{category_name}</option>
        {/categories}
</select>
```

By using the `{category_group_id}` and `{category_depth}` parameters, you can refine things further.  If you need to restrict it by category group, and indent things by depth (and `{select_options}` is inadequate), perhaps something like this would do the trick:

```
<select name="category[]" id="categories" size="4" multiple="multiple">
        {categories}
                {if category_group_id == 3}
                     <option value="{category_id}"{selected}>
                            {if category_depth == 2}&nbsp;&nbsp;{/if}{category_name}
                      </option>
                {/if}
        {/categories}
</select>
```

Comment: is there a reason why using the 2nd option above a parent category isn't auto-assigned if a child category is selected?

auto-assign to parent category is set to "Yes" in channel admin global preferences

Comment: Not sure @TadWard, sorry.